# Animation block cannot resize UiView, but can move it

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UIView on top of my appdelegate window.
When I try to resize it to make it disappear, the animation doesn't work.

**TLDR** : cannot resize a UIView with UIAnimation block, but can move it

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{ 
                     CGRect frame = viewMore.frame;
                     frame.size.height = 0;
                     viewMore.frame = frame;

                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
```

But, if I want to move the view, using this code, it works like charm.
Example :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{ 
                    CGPoint centerMore =    viewMore.center;
                     centerMore.y += viewMore.frame.size.height;
                     viewMore.center = centerMore;


                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){


                 }];
```

viewMore has 2 UIButton subviews.
The same code works to resize a UIWebView
There are something that I don't understand. 
You are my only hope (well no, you're not :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 
The problem was that the subviews (UIButton with image) weren't resize.
The solution :
Set the  [clipsToBounds](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds) to YES on the view to resize.